# How to convert Markdown to TWiki using Pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

[Pandoc documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html#general-options) says it can convert to TWiki.  But with the newest version, it gives error "Unknown writer: twiki":

```
$ brew install pandoc
$ pandoc --version | head -4
pandoc 1.17.0.3
Compiled with texmath 0.8.5, highlighting-kate 0.6.2.
Syntax highlighting is supported for the following languages:
    abc, actionscript, ada, agda, apache, asn1, asp, awk, bash, bibtex, boo, c,

$ pandoc file.md -o file.md.twiki -f markdown -t twiki
pandoc: Unknown writer: twiki
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In those docs, the list of readers and writers are separate. `twiki` only shows under readers. From this, it's clear `pandoc` supports reading `twiki` documents but not writing them.

Comment: How did I miss that? 